# How to give a default value to a parameter which has no concrete type but an interface

Tags: c#

I have this function doSomething. 99% of the time it take the same arg. I would like to create a default argument. But the type of the argument is a interface

```
    public static void doSomething(Itype arg=new classWhichImplementItype())
    {
        //do something
    }
```

> Default paramter value for arg must be a compile time constant.

How can I do

Comment: Default to `null` and add a check inline?

Comment: If 99% of time you want to call it without parameter (assuming optional parameter would work), then why not just adding the overload without parameter which will call another overload passing that default implementation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Default arguments must be compile-time constants. So, use overloads:

```
public static void doSomething()
{
    doSomething(new classWitchImplementItype());
}

public static void doSomething(Itype arg)
{
    //do something
}
```

In recent versions of C#, you can also use the arrow syntax for the overload:

```
public static void doSomething() => doSomething(new classWitchImplementItype());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public static void doSomething(Itype arg=null)
    {
          if (arg==null) arg=new classWitchImplementItype();

        //do something
    }
```

Comment: Or to be more concise `arg ??= new classWitchImplementItype();`

Comment: Yes, you are right. But I don't need a short syntax here.

Comment: No it's absolutely not needed, however, this is the exact scenario that `??=` was introduced for, so I've posed it as a suggestion.

Comment: Thank you. It is a  good reminder about another syntax. I will certainly use it

Comment: This prevents someone from explicitly passing `null` as the value, however.

Comment: And it is plus if compare with Amy suggestion